# Missing message: "app.homepage.title" for locale: "it", using default message as fallback

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I have `react-intl` set up on my webpage and I have verified that my `intl` prop contains the following:

```
{
    locale: 'it',
    messages: {
        it: {
            app.homepage.title: 'Casa'
        }
    }
}
```

Yes I get the error message:

```
[React Intl] Missing message: "app.homepage.title" for locale: "it", using default message as fallback.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am using `intl` in the following way:

```
const title = intl.formatMessage({
  id: "app.homepage.title",
  defaultMessage: "Home"
});
```

## Importing the messages

I am loading the messages from a locally-stored `json` file like so:

```
import Italian from "app/translations/it.json";
import locale_en from "react-intl/locale-data/en";
import locale_it from "react-intl/locale-data/it";

addLocaleData([...locale_en, ...locale_it]);

const loadTranslation = () => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const locale = urlParams.has("locale")
    ? urlParams.get("locale")
    : navigator.language;
  const messages = {
    it: Italian,
    en: null
  };

  return { locale, messages };
};

const { locale, messages } = loadTranslation();

...

<IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
</IntlProvider>
```

My translation file contains the following:

```
{
  "app.signup": "Iscriviti",
  "app.login": "Accesso",
  "app.homepage.title": "Casa"
}
```

Comment: How are you defining the messages?

Comment: @SergioEscudero I am loading them from a json file containing id, string pairs.

Comment: When you are saying you are loading them from a json, is that from a server or from your local files?

Comment: @SergioEscudero local files via `import`

Comment: Is that a .json or a .js file ?

Comment: @SergioEscudero definitely a `json` file. I could post the code?

Comment: It would be great, even if you can add how you are importing the file and set it up to the provider will be awesome

Comment: @SergioEscudero ok I have edited my answer with details.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out thanks. I need to return just the italian translation from the `loadTranslations` function.

Comment: You can add it to the answer and mark as correct. Thank you!

Comment: Yes will do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I figured it out. I need to modify the `loadTranslations` function like this and it works:

```
const loadTranslation = () => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const locale = urlParams.has("locale")
    ? urlParams.get("locale")
    : navigator.language;
  const messages = {
    it: Italian,
    en: null
  };

  return { locale, messages: messages[locale] };
};
```